# How to convert a given date & time in standard format to unix time?

Tags: java

I am creating a program for converting given time and date to unix time... But I am getting an error as- java.time package does not exist on this line-

```
s = java.time.Instant.parse(l[0]).getEpochSecond();
```

Comment: What version of Java are you on?

Comment: Showing your code and the full error log would help us to understand what is your problem.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run Java 8 code on an earlier system.

Comment: `java.time` is available in Java >= 8. Have you checked the version you're using?

Comment: It will be good if you print the error stack trace here. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 8 Api

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String strDate = "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
        ZonedDateTime     zdt  = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDate,dtf);        
        System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());  // 1055545912454  
    }
```

For previous Java versions

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String str = "Jun 13 2003 23:11:52.454 UTC";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz");
    Date date = df.parse(str);
    long epoch = date.getTime();
    System.out.println(epoch); // 1055545912454
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned on top for java 8 anyways i have updated the same

Comment: The problem stated in the question is *"java.time package does not exist"*. The OP is not asking how to use the API, but why the error occurs (I'm just guessing, because we can't really know why someone downvotes - but that's a good guess, I think).